# Ресурсы приложения на Андроиде

Tags: android

Недавно обратил внимание на ресурсоемкость приложения на Андроиде. Даже простейшее приложение типа ["Hello, Android"](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) занимает мегабайты. Откуда набегает эта масса?

```
$ procrank

280   15304K   15304K    2941K    1772K  com.example.hello
```

Comment: А каким образом Вы это приложение делаете? по идее там 10 kb единственный класс и все. 

Comment: сорри, я писал про память, на флэшке места немного - 200 Kb

Answer (score 3):

Память выделяется под кучу (heap) - динамическая память, jvm резервирует определенное ее количество, чтобы реже приходилось ее выделять, т.к. процедура сия достаточно ресурсоемкая. Кроме того, android и linux соответственно резервирует процессу часть оперативной памяти, которая используется в качестве кэша этого процесса (доступ быстрее чем к диску).

Показанные цифры не означают, что памяти на самом деле используется N, они лишь гарантируют, что памяти не используется больше чем N.